# Spring-Data-Elasticsearch settings: Spring can't find config file?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

With Spring-Data-Elasticsearch, I am trying to use analyzers and mappings defined in *elasticsearch_config.json*.
This JSON file is in */src/main/resources* folder.

My JAVA model looks like:

```java
@Document(indexName = "test", type="Tweet")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch_config.json")
public class Tweet {   

    @Id
    private String idStr;

    /** other fields, getters and setters are omitted **/

}
```

*elasticsearch_config.json* contains both settings and mappings:

```
{
    "settings": { /* some filters */},
    "mappings": { /* some types' mappings*/ }
}
```

I tried with curl, I get no problem indexing/searching.

**My problem**:

I want to use *@Setting* to configure my mappings (not curl), but *@Setting* annotation doesn't seem to work.
With *@Setting*, when I use curl to check my mapping, I don't get all the mappings I defined in *elasticsearch_config.json* :

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test/_mapping?pretty=true"
```

My guess is that Spring can't find the *elasticsearch_config.json* properly.
However I have already checked that *myproject/src/main/resources* is in my project's build path...

I appreciate any help, thank you!

**Notes**:
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535985/spring-data-elasticsearch-settings-using-config-file) solution that may work, but:
1. I don't understand where nodeBuilder comes from
2. I may be wrong but, isn't there a solution only using *@Setting*?

**UPDATES: My mappings**
I separeted analyzers from mappings. *mappings.json* looks like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "Tweet": {
      "_id": {
        "path":"idStr",
        "properties": {
          "idStr": {
            "type":"string",
            "index":"not_analyzed",
            "store":true
          }
        }
      },
      "numeric_detection" : true,
      "dynamic_templates": [
       {
          "id_fields": {
          "match":"userId*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type":"string",
              "index":"no",
              "store":true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name_fields": {
            "match":"*Name",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type":"string",
              "index":"no",
              "store":true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "index":"analyzed",
          "analyzer":"custom_analyzer",
          "store": true
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
          "index":"analyzed",
          "store": true
        },
        "testVersion": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index":"not_analyzed",
          "store":false
        }
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally found out why it was not working!!

Like Val said, I decomposed my *elasticsearch_config.json* file into *settings.json* and *mappings.json*.

My project/src/main/ressources architecture:

```
- mappings
    + mappings.json
- settings
    + settings.json
```

And

```java
@Document(indexName = "test", type="SentimentTweet")
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings.json")
```

However, in *mappings.json*, I should omit the field *mappings* and DIRECTLY put the content of the mapping.

INSTEAD OF:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "Tweet": {
             /* MAPPINGS CONFIGURATION ARE OMITTED */
         }
    }
}
```

Only writes in mappings.json:

```
{
    "Tweet": {
         /* MAPPINGS CONFIGURATION ARE OMITTED */
     }
}
```

The same should be done for settings.json

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Do you confirm that in your mapping you have `Tweet` as the type and in the `@Document` annotation you use `SentimentTweet` or you have the same type in both places?

Answer (score 8):

The `@Setting` annotation should point to a file containing only the `settings` part. If you also want to specify your custom mapping, you need to use the `@Mapping` annotation and give it the path to your mapping file. It goes like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "test", type="Tweet")
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings.json")
public class Tweet {   

    @Id
    private String idStr;

    /** other fields, getters and setters are omitted **/

}
```

Then you need to store `settings.json` in `myproject/src/main/resources/settings/` and `mappings.json` in `myproject/src/main/resources/mappings/`.

That should work.

Comment: Thank you, but that's still not working.. When I check my mappings with curl, I get mapping for only 3 fields, but my json contains mapping for around 10 fields.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you show your `mappings.json` file?

Comment: Thanks, then in the `@Document` annotation you should use `SentimentTweet` instead of `Tweet`. Please try it out.

Comment: Sorry, that's still not working... Even the custom analyzer that I defined in settings.json defined with @Setting cannot be found (when verifying if `@Setting` worked, with curl I got: failed to find analyzer [custom_analyzer])