# ElasticSearch custom analyzer having tokenizer "uax_url_email" for email

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, analyzer

How to configure a custom analyzer for elasticSearch in springboot? I have a problem of splitting email address while searching. for example: if email address is “alice@domain.com”, it will be splitted into “alice” and “domain.com”. I dont need this. I found, it can be fixed by creating a custom analyzer with tokenizer "uax_url_email". but I can't configure it in springboot. I will show you, how I configured and please help me to fix it.

configuration: 
**settings/settings.json :**

```
{
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_email_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
              "filter": ["lowercase", "stop"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

**settings/mappings.json:**

```
{
      "mappings": {
        "message": {
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_email_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**organization class :**

```
@Document(indexName = "organization", type="organization")
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/settings/mappings.json")
public class Organization{   

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String mail;

    /** other fields, getters and setters are omitted **/

}
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001695/4604579

Comment: its not working for me.

Comment: Please show how you've done it.

Comment: created a file "settings.json" in "src/main/resources/settings/settings.json" and saved above configuration in it. and did like this - @Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json") at top of entity class

Comment: You need to split the above file into mappings and settings and use both `@Mapping` and `@Setting` like in the link I shared above (also see the accepted answer)

Comment: Yes I did that also,but no change

Comment: Please show the content of each file and the annotations you've added

Comment: I changed my post with configuration files. please check it.

Comment: You haven't read the link I gave you carefully ;-) you need to remove `mappings` and `settings` from the files.